# Android - How to add image between ActionBar and Tabs?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

[image]

I would like to insert an image between the ActionBar and ActionBar Tabs. What is the best way do it? 
I'm using actionbarsherlock.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a bunch of research, I found there is no way to make this work with native ActionBar tabs. So save yourself some time, create your own TabHost and place it below the image. Then implement tabchange listeners, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use a layout above actionbar tab having your image or just take imageview above it.